# Common autocompletechange event for many inputs with same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-autocomplete

Is it possible to define a common autocompletechange envent for many inputs with jquery.

I have a table whose rows are dynamically added when the use click on an add button. It is a simple clone of the row. Each row contains several inputs. I started by coding an autocompletechange on the first row but I wonder if it is possible to keep only one autocompletechange to manage all inputs in row (inputs ids come to mind since I generate a new add when adding a row).

here is my code :

```
jQuery('.item').on("autocompletechange", function (event, ui) {
    callAjaxMethod();
}
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="right">
        <label>Item</label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" name="item1-1" value=""
            id="item1-1" class="input-text  item" title="Item" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.item` is the class of the div containing the input. inputs will have as I said dynamic ids.

Now, when I add many rows in my table only the first input fire the event. Note that executing jQuery('.item') in the navigator console will return an array of all my inputs...

Is there an elegant way to do this ?

Comment: Could you post the html also?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure without the row creating context, but you could create a function AddRow(...) that both creates the row and defines all the eventhandlers needed for that row.

Another way would be to create only the first row and then use the [$.clone function](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) with the argument set at true so that the event handlers are copied along the element.